# Getting conflict when setting ft=txtfmt

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I installed [The Vim Highlighter](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Txtfmt-The-Vim-Highlighter) plugin by Brett Stahlman. The plugin requires setting `filetype=txtfmt`. I set the option using `:set ft=txtfmt` but got conflicts like `Level 1 map ambiguity:[bf already mapped to <Plug>unimpairedBPrevious` and many more. I think it's because I've installed `unimpairedBPrevious` as well. I commented out `unimpairedBPrevious` entry from my .vimrc but still got few conflicts.

Could someone help me how can I resolve these conflicts without compromising any plugin's functionality?

Comment: You should first follow [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) to find out what it actually causing the problem, then you can update your question with the new information you found.

Comment: I read the answer and I can conclude the conflict is coming because of the plugin I mentioned in the question.